# location object, state property is undefined

Tags: react-router-dom

I am implementing the Link component in my NominationPage component like this:

```js
      <Link
        target={'_blank'}
        to={{
          pathname: `/nomination/${nomination.id}`,
          state: nomination,
        }}
      >
        {nomination.nominationName}
      </Link>
```

here is location object portion of console.dir(props) in child component (NominationPage):

```js
location:
hash: ""
pathname: "/nomination/9031bc06-d896-4ddb-a707-bce8c32792dc"
search: ""
state: undefined
```

Here is the router and switch:

```js
<Router>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <Switch>
        <NominationsDataProvider>
          <SearchResultDataProvider>
            <Route exact path={'/login'} component={Login} />
            <Route exact path={'/searchresults'} component={SearchResults} />
            <Route
              exact
              path={'/searchhealthprovider/:id'}
              component={SearchHealthProvider}
            />
            <Route exact path="/nomination/:id" component={NominationsPage} />
            <Route exact path={['/', '/home']} component={Home} />
            <Route
              exact
              path={'/email-verification/:token'}
              component={VerifyEmail}
            />
          </SearchResultDataProvider>
        </NominationsDataProvider>
      </Switch>
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>,
```

How can the location object's state be undefined if the id in the URL is defined and is a property of the object (nomination) that is assigned to the state property of the location object?

I have tried withRouter and useLocation Hook strategies, both console.dir's are the same.

Here is source code links for reference:

NominationPage Component with props: https://github.com/the-difference-engine/ksf/blob/272-avoid-findallnominations-refactor/packages/app/src/components/pages/NominationPage/index.js#L37

NewNomination Component with Link to NominationPage Component in jsx: https://github.com/the-difference-engine/ksf/blob/8b573b2f7de678aac560644db3f308e98ab64b80/packages/app/src/components/pages/Home/NewNomination.js#L36

Router: https://github.com/the-difference-engine/ksf/blob/8b573b2f7de678aac560644db3f308e98ab64b80/packages/app/src/index.js#L28

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by removing `target={'_blank'}` from the `<Link />` component. Making a new tab made the `state` field undefined in the `location` object.